# VUEX: Why can't we affect the whole state object?

Tags: vuex

I have a RESET mutation in my store that reset the state object to its default value : the solution I found is to `Object.assign(state, defaultState)` to make it works instead of `state = defaultState`. Affecting with `=` on a specific property works but not for the whole state Object.

Work :

```
RESET: (state) => {
  Object.assign(state, defaultState);
}
```

Don't work :

```
RESET: (state) => {
  state = defaultState;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it unsafe to be mutating state like this? Shouldn't you be copying the state object, mutating it, and then returning the new state? Also, you probably need to explicitly do a deep copy of your object. I'm not sure Flux implementations will do it for you. https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html - I know this is a Redux post, but the best practices still apply.

Comment: I think that the immutable aspect is handled internally by vuex librairie since I can see specific properties affected when a mutation is called that way in Vue debugger tool !

CF https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html

Answer (score 12):

This is due to the way js works. When you set a new object with `=` it's a totally new object with a new address in memory, so vuex no longer knows how to track it.

When you use `Object.assign(state, defaultState);`, it's essentially keeps the same object and it just sets the properties to the new values.

Comment: So the `state` variable passed into the mutation is a pointer to the state object in memory. But `state = defaultState` modifies the pointer to point to `defaultState`. `state` still exists in the memory as it was before. In other words `state = ...` modifies the pointer, not the object pointed at. `Object.assign()` however replaces the whole object in memory, thus it is reflected in every other place which has the same pointer. (Right?)